# "ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined" When trying to list calendar events

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I copied this code directly from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar), but when I try to run it I keep getting the same error:

> "ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined"

It cites line 9 as the issue:

```
const events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
/**
 * Lists the next 10 upcoming events in the user's default calendar.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list
 */
function listNext10Events() {
  const calendarId = 'primary';
  const now = new Date();
  const events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 10
  });
  if (!events.items || events.items.length === 0) {
    console.log('No events found.');
    return;
  }
  for (const event of events.items) {
    if (event.start.date) {
      // All-day event.
      const start = new Date(event.start.date);
      console.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleDateString());
      return;
    }
    const start = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
    console.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleString());
  }
}
```

I've gone into my Google Cloud console and enabled Cal and Sheets APIs, but I don't know what else I can do. No change in error result from doing so.

Comment: Please remove the `java` tag -- this seems unrelated to Java.

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

Enable advanced services
To use an advanced Google service, follow these instructions:

- Open the Apps Script project.
- At the left, click Editor code.
- At the left, next to Services, click Add a service add.
- Select an advanced Google service and click Add.